# In my Meteor app, How can I update an object in my collection with new data replacing the old

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor app, I'm having an issue updating data I inserted.

In console, typing `MyCollection.insert({sometext: "hello"});` I insert "hello" for sometext. Now as you can see in the code below, the template `infoOutput` with the `{{output.sometext}}` returns what I have inserted.

Now in console when I type:

`MyCollection.update(this._id, {sometext: "hi again"});` I get back "undefined". I'm just trying to update the string that I set in my database for sometext, which was "hello", with the new string "hi again" or whatever else I want. I just need to what to type into the console instead of `MyCollection.update(this._id, {sometext: "hi again"});` or if that's not the problem, I would like to know what is, and what I can do to fix it.

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

In my client.js file I have:

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('MyCollection');
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.infooutput.output = function() { 
           return MyCollection.findOne(); 
    }
}
```

In my server.js file I have:

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('MyCollection');
if (Meteor.isServer) {
}
```

I have a template:

```
<template name="infoOutput">
<div id="outputText">
{{output.sometext}} 
</div>
</template>
```

and then in my main page

```
<body>
{{>infoOutput}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console `this` is the window object and won't have an _id property. Instead, you should get an explicit reference to the collection cursor you want:

```
var theId = MyCollection.findOne()._id;
MyCollection.update({_id: theId}, {$set: {sometext: "hi again"}});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting an "undefined" in the console and no changes made.

Comment: Also, when removing autopublish and insecure and attempting to update with the code above, actually I even used the actual id itself too, I get: update failed: Access denied

Comment: Mistake on my part. Didn't realize "sometext" wasn't the name I was using.

Comment: Hi @dave thanks for the correction. But next time you find an answer that is almost correct, instead of posting a slightly modified new answer, please go ahead and fix the original one. This is how SO is supposed to work and will provide clutter-free Q&A :)

Comment: Sorry Serkan Durusoy I didn't really I could edit answers that weren't my own!

Answer (score 0):

Try `MyCollection.update(this._id, {$set: {sometext: "hi again"}}); for size.`